Is this possible to control visibility of buttons add products and edit products on Order products related list?
The only solution that we have found so far is to hide two buttons altogether by leveraging  Show list view action bar and having two duplicating related list section, one hidden under custom permission

However, in this approach, we won't be able to hide one button out of two.

Is there any way to hide a single button or show a single button?
I understand that if users click the button they would receive errors if they don't have permissions to Add or Edit products, but we would like to find a solution to avoid these errors but inside hide the corresponding buttons.

Are you controlling access via profile?

Mostly PS and PSG

I see okay, added 2 variations of answers, one is controlling using Profile and another one leveraging PS, which could also be leveraged using PSG. To other readers: PS = Permission Set, PSG = Permission Set Group

1. First Approach (Using Profile)
By using **Page Layout** we can achieve this. One way to control this is by creating 2-3 (depending on your permutations) page layouts and hide the button within the Page Layout itself.
Here's a scenario, assuming I have 2 different users, where their difference in working with "OrderItem" (Order Product) is different, like below:

User A: Access both Edit Products and Add Products on the Order Products related list.
User B: Access only "Edit Products" on the Order Products related list.

Now I would create another different Page Layout (for User B) (cloned from standard, in this example) and check only the button I want to show, like this:

I would then assign this Page Layout to the different Profile. In this example, User B is using System Admin Profile (just as an example), so assign this new Page Layout (which only can Edit Products for OrderItem) to User B's profile, which is System Administator.

Then finally, when User B view the Order record, in the related list, for Order Products, user only see the "Edit Products" button:


2. Different Approach (using RecordType + Permission Set) 
This second approach is almost similar to the first one, except that, now we are using RecordType. This is useful, when we are using Permission Set to control this behaviour.
Here are the steps, for this second approach

Create Page Layouts (depending on use case/permutations)
Create new RecordTypes for each Page Layouts (For example, if we created 2 new Page Layouts, then we will be creating 3 different RecordTypes).
Create Permission Set, under Order object, assign the RecordTypes accordingly. Which also follows the same number of RecordTypes created, in this case, which is 2.
Finally, assign the permission set to the users.



well, we use a single Profile and a single Record Type

@Patlatus To achieve this without custom code, this seems to be the way right now. I think, if you were to only use single Profile and single Record Type, then have to custom build the related list with LWC
